# Getting values from td using .closest is not giving out value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create the table like so:

```
<table class="table" id="tbl_items">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Item
        </th>
        <th>
            Serial Key
        </th>
        <th>
            Brand
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.AccountID = item.AccountId.ToString();
        if (item.Items != null)
        {
            foreach (var itemOnList in item.Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="cls-itemid" data-itemid="@itemOnList.ItemId">@Html.DisplayFor(model => itemOnList.ItemId)</td>
                    <td class="cls-itemname" data-itemname="@itemOnList.ItemName">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.ItemName)</td>
                    <td class="cls-serialnumber" data-serialnumber="@itemOnList.SerialNumber">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.SerialNumber)</td>
                    <td class="cls-brandname" data-brandname="@itemOnList.BrandName">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.BrandName)</td>
                    <td class="cls-quantity" data-quantity="@itemOnList.Quantity">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.Quantity)</td>
                    <td class="cls-description" data-description="@itemOnList.Description">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.Description)</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-itemid="@itemOnList.ItemId" class="btn_edit">Edit |</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-itemid="@itemOnList.ItemId" class="btn_delete">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

I am trying to get the value of td in a row using this:

```
$(".btn_edit").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var text = row.find(".cls-itemname").text();
    alert(text);
});
```

The alert box has no value. I cannot use the data-item because when I change the value of the @Html.EditorFor boxes, it gives the old values and not the new ones.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? I doubt any will display as the alert would no doubt give `undefined`. Maybe `console.log(row);` and see if the console outputs what you are expecting? Then move on to `console.log(text);` if the output is correct for `row`.

Comment: Isn't content of `.cls-itemname` an input control (`@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.ItemName)`) ? What text do you expect to get?

Comment: I do not get any errors when I user console.log(row) and (text) but with console.row() I get the "cells
:
(7) [td.cls-itemid, td.cls-itemname, td.cls-serialnumber, td.cls-brandname, td.cls-quantity, td.cls-description, td]" on the console.log(text), it's just blank.

Comment: your given code worked for me:-https://jsfiddle.net/o38cqxq1/  (i think you don't have `<table></table>` there which cause the problem). Can you show your rendered html code , not this foreach generated code. Actual rendered code (copy through inspect element and paste in your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use [`@Html.DisplayFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx) which returns an `<input>` element... I guess you want to have the input's text...

This will work:

```
$(".btn_edit").click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var text = row.find(".cls-itemname input").val();  // <-- Look the change here
  alert(text);
});
```

There is simply no text in the `.cls-itemname` element... But there's an `input` having a `value`. Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) against the `input`.